# imacros extract table with specific width

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xpath, imacros

Hi I am trying to extract a table's from a web page. The table has no id however it has a unique length 750px and width 500px  and is found in Frame 2.

The following code,sometimes works and sometimes doesnt as it seems the POS might change.

```
FRAME F=2 
TAG POS=6 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=WIDTH:* EXTRACT=HTM
```

The following code doesnt work at all.

```
 FRAME F=2 
 TAG POS=6 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=WIDTH:500* EXTRACT=HTM
```

How can I extract what I want perhaps using the SEARCH commands as I know the length and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the frame there is only one table of 500px width, you should use `POS=1` :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=WIDTH:500* EXTRACT=HTM
```